# Removing elements from a list which are much larger or much smaller than most of the elements of list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, list-comprehension

I have some images whose size are stored as list of tuples, as below:

```
(79, 1100)
(51, 1100)
(56, 1100)
(49, 1100)
(47, 1100)
(44, 1100)
(54, 1100)
(15,1100)
(52, 1100)
(115, 1100)
(44, 1100)
(60, 1100)
(51, 1100)
(56, 1100)
(19,1100)
(110,1100)
```

What I want is to remove all the images whose first dimension is much smaller/larger (in this case 15,115,19,110) than most of the elements in the list. Here I can't define a threshold as the range of the numbers (in first dimension) can change much depending on the scale of image I choose.

Comment: You can't really define 'much' without setting a factor that would be 'much'.. if you want to accomplish this, you would probably just use a maximum % difference from average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the mean and the standard deviation of your image dimensions to build a threshold.
Let's use numpy to calculate these metrics:

```
import numpy as np

#convert the list of tuples l_tuples to a numpy array:
l_new = np.array(l_tuples)

#calculate the mean and standard deviation of the first column
mean=np.mean(l_new,axis=0)[0]
std=np.std(l_new,axis=0)[0]

#create a mask to find all elements which are in the interval [mean-std, mean+std]
mask=[abs(x[0]-mean)<std for x in l_new]

#pictures you want to use:
accepted = l_new[mask]
#pictures you dont want to use:
remove = l_new[[not i for i in mask]]
```

If you feel that one standard deviation is not a good estimate for you, you can easily exchange this metric with something different, like a fixed percentage of the mean or whatever.